# Android: Able to read Japanese characters in test app, but same code doesn't work in main app

Tags: java, android, utf-8

This makes no sense to me at all, but then I'm a newb. When I debug in a stripped-down test app I can see clearly that the code is reading the Japanese text, but when I drop the code into my main app and debug I see it reading each line, but garbling the Japanese characters. Any idea what could be influencing this?

```
String[] fileList = {"file1", "file2", ...
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            int rawId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(fileList[i], "raw", this.getPackageName());
            FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(fileList[i], Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            InputStream read = this.getResources().openRawResource(rawId);
            InputStreamReader inputstreamReader = new InputStreamReader(read, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamReader);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line + "\n"; 

               // Japanese characters in "line" appear correct here 
               // in test app but not in main app.

                out.write(line.getBytes());
            }
            inputstreamReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`line.getBytes()` gives you the bytes from the string using the platform default encoding, which is probably different between the test app and the main app. Use `out.write(line.getBytes("UTF-8"))` to ensure you're writing the bytes out UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Thanks JP, the problem is happening at the read stage, before it attempts to write. The file it's reading from, by the way, is stored in the raw folder.

Comment: Ah, ok, it wasn't clear from your original answer. Maybe compare the bytes read between the test app and the main app to be 100% sure you're reading the same bytes (raw files are the same, etc.)?

Comment: Yeah, it has to be something in the environment, I guess I'll just have to try to smoke out the culprit somehow.